# problem in importing private key to the token

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11, yubico, pkcs

I am trying to inject an der formated private key to a PKC11 compatible token, with the below command:

```
pkcs11-tool --module /path_tp/libparskey11.so --login --write-object private.der --type privkey --id 21 --label injected
```

but I got the below result and the key doesn't import in the token.

```
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Logging in to "token-testyunes".
Please enter User PIN: 
Created private key:
Private Key Object; RSA 
  label:      injected
  ID:         21
  Usage:      decrypt, sign
warning: PKCS11 function C_GetAttributeValue(ALWAYS_AUTHENTICATE) failed: rv = CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID (0x12)

  Access:     sensitive, extractable
```

but I can successfully import public keys and certificates in the token with the same procedure. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you ever been successfully import any private key this way onto this token?

Comment: Some device's manufacturers can prohibit importing keys onto token or allow with restrictions.

Comment: I suggest you must not to import private key - you mus unwrap it.